# Resourcess to study matching (game theory)

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, algorithms, matching

I want to study matching markets, algorithms etc. in a fairly comprehensive way. I would want to learn the theory primarily, but books that offer applications as examples would be preferable as long as the theory is covered well.

What are some good textbooks/ notes etc. that can be used for this?

Comment: Not a book, but this might be a good starting point for getting into deep water fast: [25th Jerusalem School in Economic Theory
Matching and Market Design (recordings)](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTn74Qx5mPsSvU93UHDWmLxo2sMHQuFJI)

Comment: This book has a nice introductory chapter (ch. 10) on Matching Markets, and it's even downloadable for free: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/

Answer (score 1):

We used [Optimal Transport Methods in Economics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691172767/optimal-transport-methods-in-economics) by Alfred Galichon in a graduate level class